# How to perform in place replacement of multiple substrings in python

Tags: python, string, ip

I have the a user supplied string which contains one or more IP addresses I need to augment this with the reverse dns lookup for each. My code currently works fine for a single IP and I'm looking to make it capable of performing the replacement on multiple IPs in the string. What would be the best way of doing this?

```
import re
import socket

line = "this is my IP address 8.8.8.8 and my mac address is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.";
print("Before: " + line)
ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
try:
    domain_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip[0])[0]
except socket.gaierror:
    domain_name = "No Reverse"
except socket.herror:
    domain_name = "InvalidIP"

ipd = ip[0] + " [" + domain_name + "]"
line = line.replace(ip[0], ipd)
print("After: " + line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your code using a for loop.

```py
>>> line = "this is my IP address 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 and my mac address is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF."
>>> print("Before: " + line)
Before: this is my IP address 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 and my mac address is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.
>>> ips = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
>>> 
>>> for ip in ips:
...     try:
...         domain_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
...     except socket.gaierror:
...         domain_name = "No Reverse"
...     except socket.herror:
...         domain_name = "InvalidIP"
...     ipd = ip + " [" + domain_name + "]"
...     line = line.replace(ip, ipd)
... 
>>> print("After: " + line)
After: this is my IP address 8.8.8.8 [dns.google] or 8.8.4.4 [dns.google] and my mac address is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string 'line' by using the line.split() and make a list of all items. Then iterate through the list to find one or multiple IP addresses in the line string. All the IP addresses could be stored in a list.

```
line = "this is my IP address 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9 my mac address is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.";
a =[]
for i in line.split():
  ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', i)
  if len(ip)!=0:
    a.append(ip)
print (a)
```

When you have a string containing 2 IP addresses the output will be:
[['8.8.8.8'], ['9.9.9.9']]